elliptic estimates for Hermitian line bundles on Kahler manifolds
Suppose $(M,\omega)$ is a compact Kahler manifold with $Ric\geq -1$. $L$ is a line bundle with curvature $\sqrt{-1}\Omega_L=\omega$.
Let $u\in \Omega^{n,0}(M)$, I'm told that by elliptic estimate,
$$
\|u\|_{C^{2,\alpha}}\leq C(\|u\|_{L^2}+\|\bar{\partial}u\|_{C^{\alpha}}).
$$
and
$$
\|u\|_{L^{\infty}}\leq C(\|u\|_{L^2}+\|\bar{\partial}u\|_{L^{\infty}}).
$$
But I don't know which estimate the author used here. Can anyone explain it for me or give a reference? Thanks in advance.

Is the PDE you are looking at given by $ \bar{\partial}u=0$?

@F. Conrad I'm afraid not. Here $u$ is just a smooth form valued over $L$, but not holomorphic. But if $\bar{\partial}u=0$, then the Hodge laplacian of $u$ equals to $0$, i.e. $\Delta_{\bar{\partial}}u=0$, which is a second-ordered elliptic equation, and usual elliptic estimates help us to get these formulae. However I have no ideal in this general case.

Might be some version of the Schauder estimates for the elliptic operator $L:u\mapsto \bar{\partial}u$. They give you some estimate of the form $$\lVert u\rVert_{C^{2,\alpha}}<C\left(\lVert L(u)\rVert_{C^{\alpha}}+\lVert u\rVert_{L^\infty}\right).$$ I'm not really sure though, sorry!
